# Self referential View/Context bound

Tags: scala, context-bound

I am actually not clear whether the following were a view or context bound.  Also not clear what the self referential aspect (re-referencing Model) is doing ;) :

```
abstract class Model[M <: Model[M]] extends Transformer {
```

An explanation on the meaning of "<: Model[M]" would be appreciated.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov OP updated

Comment: Upper type bounds in general are explained [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/upper-type-bounds.html). Do you want some theoretical background or a more detailed example for the self referential aspect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<:` is neither a view nor context bound, but a type bound.

Below is an extended example of how self referential type bounds can be used.

The class `ModelA` uses a more restrictive type bound `M <: ModelA[M]` in order to make the method `fooN` work. `ModelA2` can still extend `ModelA[ModelA1]`, but not `ModelA[ModelB1]`. On the other hand, the class `ModelB` doesn't further restrict the type bound, so `ModelB2` can extend `ModelB[ModelA1]`. The methods `bar1` and `bar2` restrict either the type bound or the parameter `model`, depending on the order in which the methods `transform` and `bar` are called on `model`.

```
object Main extends App {
  val a: ModelA1 = foo(new ModelA1(), 2)
  val b: ModelA1 = foo(new ModelA2(), 3)
  val c: ModelB1 = bar1(new ModelB1())
  val d: ModelA1 = bar2(new ModelB2())

  def foo[M <: ModelA[M]](model: Model[M], n: Int): M = model.transform.fooN(n)

  def bar1[M <: ModelB[M]](model: Model[M]): M = model.transform.bar

  def bar2[M <: Model[M]](model: ModelB[M]): M = model.bar.transform
}

abstract class Model[M <: Model[M]] {
  def transform: M
}

abstract class ModelA[M <: ModelA[M]] extends Model[M] {
  def foo: M

  def fooN(n: Int): M = {
    var x: M = this.foo
    for (_ <- 2 to n)
      x = x.foo
    x
  }
}

abstract class ModelB[M <: Model[M]] extends Model[M] {
  def bar: M
}

class ModelA1 extends ModelA[ModelA1] {
  override def transform: ModelA1 = ???
  override def foo: ModelA1 = ???
}

class ModelA2 extends ModelA[ModelA1] {
  override def transform: ModelA1 = ???
  override def foo: ModelA1 = ???
}

class ModelB1 extends ModelB[ModelB1] {
  override def transform: ModelB1 = ???
  override def bar: ModelB1 = ???
}

class ModelB2 extends ModelB[ModelA1] {
  override def transform: ModelA1 = ???
  override def bar: ModelA1 = ???
}
```

Comment: OK thanks for pointing out this is a Type Bound.  Now I still do not understand why the bounds are on Model[M] which is a self referential type bound.

Comment: I have expanded my example.